# Getting Individual Filenames in Automator

Tags: applescript, bash, automator, script

The idea behind a small project I'm working on is to be able to upload a music file and have After Effects pick it up and render it within a video file template I have.

**The workflow would be:**

Once I upload a new music file to a folder in my iCloud Drive which would be monitored monitored by my iMac. Each new music file triggers an Adobe script which imports the new track to an Adobe After Effects project which exports it to AME and then quits. The music is then moved to another directory.

I've ran in to an issue with passing in a filename to an Adobe script, so to work around this have made a template Adobe script with a placeholder filename (the file path would always be the same) which can be duplicated, have the placeholder filename replaced (via a batch script, though there could be a simpler way of doing it I'd suspect), executed and then deleted.

As a first pass I've been trying to focus on getting the name of new files to the folder, now with mixed success. When running an **AppleScript** *script* (.scpt) file attached to the folder I'm able to get the file name displayed and passed to a batch file. The issue now is that it doesn't seem to work with the Automator equivalent.

**Code below:**

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseItems
repeat with i from 1 to count theseItems
    try
        set thisItem to item i in theseItems
        set thisItemsInfo to info for thisItem
        set thisItemsFileName to quoted form of name in thisItemsInfo
        display dialog thisItemsFileName buttons {"Continue"}
        do shell script "/Users/jeffolaa/ReplaceName.sh " & thisItemsFileName
    end try
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

The ReplaceName batch is a single command:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i.bu 's/EDITTHIS/'$1'/' /Users/jeffolaa/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Documents/Adobe\ Scripts/AddMusicExport.jsx
```

So far my Automator workflow looks like so:

[image]

All help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer was written based on the original posting of the question and in particular the first three paragraphs of this answer, sans this note. Since then, the OP has been updated to address what was expressed in the first three paragraphs and they may now seem out of context. However, looking at the edit history of the OP one can see the relevance in context of the original question. They will remain for now until I have the time to make an appropriate edit.

---

Sorry, but your question is not that well defined and it's not totally clear what *actions* you added to the **Automator Folder Action** *workflow*, sans the obvious **Run AppleScript** *action*. Nor is it clear if there are any *actions* added before or after the **Run AppleScript** *action*. Additionally, it's not clear what code is in `/Users/jeffolaa/pointer.sh` or all of what it's doing. Which leads me to believe that just passing the `name` of the *file* to `pointer.sh` may not be enough. Although without seeing the *code* in `pointer.sh`, at this point only you know.

Also, the *form* of the **AppleScript** *code* you've shown in the OP is not the proper *form* for an **Automator Folder Action** *workflow* using a **Run AppleScript** *action*. The `on adding folder items` *handler* is of the *type* used in an **AppleScript** *script* (.scpt) file that is manually assigned to the *target folder* using the **Folder Action Setup...** *command* from the **Services** *context menu* in **Finder**, not **Automator**, where you need to use the `on input` *handler* in the **Run AppleScript** *action*.

You also have no *error handling code*, which is important in **Folder Actions** and the type and amount can depend on what you have coded in the `pointer.sh`. In other words, you might want to filter the items added to the folder by type, making sure it's a file not a folder, or a particular type of file with a given extension, etc. This can be done in **Automator** before it gets to the **Run AppleScript** *action*, or in the *code* of the **Run AppleScript** *action*, or in the *code* in `pointer.sh`, or a combination of any or all of them.

---

With that said, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is a minimal coding of what makes sense to be able to pass the ***quoted fully qualified pathname*** of the file(s) added to the *target folder* you set in **Automator's Folder Action receives file and folders added to [*folder*]** to pass to  `pointer.sh`, as that's typical of an *argument* passed to a *shell command*.

Minimal *example* **AppleScript** *code* for use in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator Folder Action** *workflow*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with i from 1 to count input
        try
            set thisItem to item i in input
            set thisItemsPathname to quoted form of POSIX path of thisItem
            do shell script "/Users/jeffolaa/pointer.sh " & thisItemsPathname
        end try
    end repeat
end run
```

Minimal *example* **AppleScript** *code* for use in an **AppleScript** *script* (.scpt) file manually assigned to the *target folder* using the **Folder Action Setup...** *command* from the **Services** *context menu* in **Finder**:

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseItems
    repeat with i from 1 to count theseItems
        try
            set thisItem to item i in theseItems
            set thisItemsPathname to quoted form of POSIX path of thisItem
            do shell script "/Users/jeffolaa/pointer.sh " & thisItemsPathname
        end try
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

- Note: To use an **AppleScript** *script* (.scpt) file using the **Folder Action Setup...** *command* from the **Services** *context menu* in **Finder**, it first must be added to the `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` folder that's within your **Home** folder.

To test the above *code*, I created the `/Users/jeffolaa/pointer.sh` file with the following *code* in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

mv "$1" "$HOME/Test/"
```

Which simply moves the files back to the folder from which they were dragged from to the *target folder* the **Folder Action** is assigned to, which is a folder within the **Test** folder. This let me know it was working properly as coded.

---

Now if it's just the `name` of the *file* you want to pass to `pointer.sh`, you can use the following:

Minimal *example* **AppleScript** *code* for use in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator Folder Action** *workflow*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with i from 1 to count input
        try
            set thisItem to item i in input
            set thisItemsInfo to info for thisItem
            set thisItemsFileName to quoted form of name in thisItemsInfo
            do shell script "/Users/jeffolaa/pointer.sh " & thisItemsFileName
        end try
    end repeat
end run
```

Minimal *example* **AppleScript** *code* for use in an **AppleScript** *script* (.scpt) file manually assigned to the *target folder* using the **Folder Action Setup...** *command* from the **Services** *context menu* in **Finder**:

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseItems
    repeat with i from 1 to count theseItems
        try
            set thisItem to item i in theseItems
            set thisItemsInfo to info for thisItem
            set thisItemsFileName to quoted form of name in thisItemsInfo
            do shell script "/Users/jeffolaa/pointer.sh " & thisItemsFileName
        end try
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

- Note: To use an **AppleScript** *script* (.scpt) file using the **Folder Action Setup...** *command* from the **Services** *context menu* in **Finder**, it first must be added to the `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` folder that's within your **Home** folder.

To test the above *code*, I edited the `pointer.sh` file with the following code in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

say "$1"
```

Which simply says the `name` of the file held in `thisItemsFileName`, which let me know it was working properly as coded.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above is just that, and sans wrapping it in a `try` *statement*, does not include any other *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any appropriate *error handling* for any *example code* presented and or *code* written by the oneself.

That said, if you'd update your question to fill in the missing pieces as mentioned in the opening paragraphs of my answer, I'll be glad to edit these *code examples* to reflect what appropriate *error handling* should be added. There's just no sense adding it until I know the particulars.

Comment: Wow, first of all massive thanks for this incredibly detailed response! It's already been amazingly helpful and really helped to get my head around Automator v AppleScript.

I've updated the original post to hopefully give some more insight in to what I'm trying to achieve and where I'm up to.

I've had varying degrees of success using your examples. I've been able to create an AppleScript script and attach it to the folder and create a message giving me the filename which is great!  Though I can't seem to get it to work in automator or pass it through to batch. Thanks again @user3439894

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve my blocker thanks to some amazing suggestions from @user34393894.

Instead of using Automator I was able to get the outcome I needed through an AppleScript script attached as a Folder Action.

For anyone interested the code I'm now using which is getting great results is:

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseItems
repeat with i from 1 to count theseItems
    try
        set thisItem to item i in theseItems
        set thisItemsInfo to info for thisItem
        set thisItemsFileName to quoted form of name in thisItemsInfo

        tell application "System Events" -- get item info
            set theKind to kind of thisItem
            set theExtension to name extension of thisItem
        end tell

        if theKind is "Folder" then
            -- do folder stuff
        else if theExtension is "mp3" then

            do shell script "/Users/jeffolaa/ReplaceName.sh " & thisItemsFileName

        end if          
    end try
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

If anyone has any feedback or builds on the code that would be greatly appreciated, always looking to improve!

Comment: There really is no need to use `System Events` to _get item info_, as `info for` is an AppleScript built-in and that was already done and is contained in `thisItemsInfo` for `thisItem`. That is, the line `set thisItemsInfo to info for thisItem` already contains the _info_, just access it like done in the next line but  as appropriate for the _value_ of the _property_ you want to retrieve, e.g.: `set theKind to kind in thisItemsInfo`